# Paypal integration - IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, checkout

I am currently trying to integrate paypal checkout with our online store. We are testing against Sandbox. Everything but the IPN (Instant payment notification) works.

We read a lot about paypal changing their security model so we tried to follow their guide but we are still getting an error:

The SSL certificate for the host could not be verified

the error we get on IPN is:

The SSL certificate for the host could not be verified

Now, we are using a G2 cert from GoDaddy (supports sha256). Not sure if this has anything to do with it or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am running out of ideas. We already installed the G5 root cert from Verisign, the site runs in SSL via G2 GoDaddy cert.

Thanks,
Moz

Comment: Are you getting any error while running the following code from your website hosted server?

curl https://tlstest.paypal.com

Comment: that actually works when I open that url on the server. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cURL to get the VERIFIED response?
If yes then contact GoDaddy and get the version number of SSL you have.

cURL by default uses SSLv3.
I had a similar issue, solved it by adding this 
    `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 2);`
to my cURL headers.

Comment: I am using woocommerce within wordpress. I am not completely sure what the software uses. Might have to reverse engineer to know. Are you aware of woocommerce?

Comment: No, but this is purely a hosting problem and it due to their non-standard security measures. Try to contact GoDaddy.